# Looking for an obscure 80s movie that happened in a neighbor's house at night

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

All I recall is the layout of the neighborhood in which the film happened. The story mainly happened in a house that was kinda perched on a small hill in a dead end street that looked like the same neighborhood of Poltergeist.

The story happened mostly at night and a guy kept going, covertly, into that house to search for something or someone. He was sneaking in.

I'm sorry for the vague description but I remember almost nothing about it but somehow it sticks in my head for some reason.

Comment: What is it that makes you think this is a sci-fi movie?

Answer (score 4):

### The Burbs (1989)

If what you're looking for is a dark comedy, it's probably [The Burbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_%27Burbs) (1989), starring Tom Hanks.

In the film, bored suburbanite Ray Peterson (Hanks) becomes convinced that his mysterious new neighbors, the Klopeks, are secretly serial killers. He and his buddies undertake several absurd attempts to prove this, including sneaking into the Klopek's yard & house on several occasions.

---

### Disturbia (2007)

Alternatively, if what you're looking for is more of a horror/thriller, it may be [Disturbia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disturbia_(film)) (2007).

Teenager Kale Brecht is confined to his house for assaulting a teacher. While observing his neighbors, he becomes convinced that his mysterious neighbor is actually a murderer who abducts and kills women. Multiple incursions into the neighbor's home - mostly at night while the neighbor is away - further confuse the situation & ratchet up the tension felt by Kale.

Comment: I instantly thought of the Burbs when reading that description. An underrated Tom Hanks classic.

Comment: Burbs was my immediate thought too, but the "obscure" part makes it a bit of a stretch. Certainly not one of his more popular works, but can anything with Hanks really be "obscure"?

Answer (score 2):

How about [Fright Night(1985)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fright_Night). A young man finds out his next door neighbor is a vampire, but no one will believe him.

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen the remake, but in the original Fright Night, Charlie & Vincent only sneak into the house once (at the end to kill Jerry) - the only other time they enter the house is during the day, and it's by knocking on the front door and being invited in.

Answer (score 1):

How about [The People Under the Stairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People_Under_the_Stairs)? While not a dead end, the house is set down a longish driveway, and the main character was sneaking in at night. Initially, it's because he's casing the place for a robbery (the home-owners own most of the houses in the neighborhood, and it's rumored that they have a hidden treasure), but later to save someone he finds in there.